# Cannot resolve Android javax.security.sasl?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, javax

I want to use javax.security.sasl.SaslClient and javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory classes. The problem is that they cannot be recognized in Android. I found and integrate add javax-sasl.jar, but it has problems with the android.jar.javax library.
How can I resolve it ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: _"but it has problems with the android.jar.javax library"_ What's that?

Comment: It is usuall jre library which is located in External Libraries folder below <1.8>.rt.jar

Comment: If you're asking this because you're trying to use JavaMail in Android, be sure to read the [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) page.

Comment: Yes I need to use javamail in android but I don't whant to use 1.5.5 version due to its slowness, I need to integrate 1.4.4 version but it gives some problems with google auth2 and that is why I need javax-sasl.jar

Comment: Using a profiler, what is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435457/mimemessage-savechanges-is-really-slow/44438011#44438011) in JavaMail 1.5.5?